# Error - org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file:

Tags: encryption, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I have got error like "**org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import android.util.Base64; import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec; import . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: def not found in namespace** "    while running the below Piece ofcode in Jmeter:

```
import android.util.Base64;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;

String Original_String= ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();
String Trim1=Original_String.substring(0, Original_String.lastIndexOf(","));
String Trim2=Trim1.replaceFirst("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
String Trim3=Trim2.replaceFirst("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
String[] parts = Trim3.split(":");
String myString = parts[1].substring(1, parts[1].length()-1);
String final_string=myString.replaceAll("\\\\n", "");
log.info(final_string);
String input="4000221111111111";

try{
        byte[] byteKey = Base64.decode(final_string.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(byteKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        Key k=kf.generatePublic(X509publicKey);
        //return (PublicKey) k;
        def cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPPadding", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
        SampleResult.setResponseData( Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP));
}
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have placed the  android.util.Base64 jar file on my lib folder of Jmeter. Help on this is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re using Beanshell, def in your script should be var.

Otherwise switch to groovy by using JSR223 Test element

Comment: Tried with the JSR223 Sampler too, but no response data from the Sampler .

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error as you're  trying to use [Groovy `def` keyword](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-syntax.html#_keywords) in the Beanshell sampler which is not supported there, the options are in:

1. Remove it completely, in Beanshell you can initialize your `cipher` variable without any helper keywords like:

   ```
   cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPPadding", "BC");
   ```
2. (better) Switch to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and make sure `groovy` is selected in the "Language" dropdown. Since JMeter 3.1 it is [recommended](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) to use Groovy for scripting as it has [much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

Comment: Tried with the JSR223 Sampler too, but no response data from the Sampler . No idea what went wrong :(